# name not defined with tkinter textvariable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to work with textvariable (python3) to change the text of Label widget, I am getting.... NameError: name 'w01' is not defined

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def dofunc():
    w01.config(text='ok1')

root = Tk()

w_id = ['w01','w02','w03','w04','w05']
for i in range(5):    
        print('print >> ',w_id[i])
        w_id[i] = StringVar()
        w=Label(root,width=5,textvariable=w_id[i])
        w.pack()

root.geometry("+50+50")
root.after(500, dofunc)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are getting that error because `w01` is not defined.  What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: can you please guide me to define the name

Answer (score 0):

i think you should like this

```
w_id = [] 
for i in range(5): 
    v= StringVar()                                            
    w=Label(root,width=5,textvariable=v)     
    w_id.append(v)
    w.pack()
```